# Homepage displays different texts and modules on other PCs

Tags: html, css, web

When I edit the homepage and click save everything looks good, But then I check the homepage with another computer and the texts,modules are displaying wrong or sametimes the text wont appear or some modules wont display.....
Ive been googling but havent seen anyone with the exact same problem....
I guess the main problem is because the website is obsolete....
Thanks in advance

Comment: Any chance you could show us some code, give us some more information. It's very hard to make anything out of the information you have supplied.

Comment: I guess some different browsers don't follow universal tags in some cases.e.g `blink` tag does not [work](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text.asp) in IE.Strange but true!!

Answer (score 2):

Have you opened your website in all the main browsers : Opera, Chrome, IE, Firefix, Safari, etc..

There is probably a problem with the way it loads in versions of the one or more browsers.
This needs to be addressed in your CSS

Comment: +1 for mentioning Opera first! :)